# Denied PTO AFTER approval

Tags: human-resources

Next week, my family and I take off for a family wedding in Las Vegas. My mother works at a major league baseball field as a retail supervisor. She requested the time off before the baseball schedule had been established, and her time off was approved. However, 7 days before we leave, her PTO has now been revoked due to a very popular opposing team playing those days. She has already paid for the trip. Should she request to be reimbursed for the value of the trip? Should she protest due to the fact that she was approved prior? I feel that as soon as the schedule was established, they should have revoked the time off; not one week prior.

Comment: She should be re-imbursed not only for her costs but the cost of all family members that need to change their plans.

Comment: @Kalen PTO? This is an international forum, so please [edit] and explain. It it also smart to add a country tag to the question, because country-specific rules/issues may apply.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is applicable labor law here; but if her contract states that she can be called in for such cases, then I'm afraid she cannot do much.

Otherwise, she should definitely raise this issue to her management/HR.